# Load html content string with \" in iOS. Because due to that css for html file is not working

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

My Problem is that I am getting html content form backEnd so when I had convert my `NSData` by using this code:

```
dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

I have got content like this:

```
<div class=\"dropzone-container\"
```

Where on the place of `"` it will automatically convert it into `\"` and due that when I load that data on `UIWebView` it would not load it respective css so I need to it to be converted like this:

```
<div class="dropzone-container"
```

Please help in this Thanks in advance........ :(

Comment: How do you load the data exactly? Are you using `dict` `description` method?

Comment: You are parsing data as json, but in yours content looks is xml.

Comment: data =     {
        "created_at" = "2016-01-20 06:56:21";
     
        "file_size" = 36737;
        id = 66;
        image = "https://staging.jobprogress.com/api/public/uploads/estimations/66_1453272981.jpg";
        "is_file" = 0;
        "job_id" = 89;
        template = "\n        <div class=\"dropzone-container\" style=\"background-color:#dcf76f;\">\n

Comment: above is snip of my response i have getting from backend Template: key contain html content here i have share only some portion of html content. It works well if have put same code on html file locally on my system and replacing \" with " but how would i replace \" in  objective c ?

Comment: Now I have successfully removed back slash from my html content but still css is not working

Comment: How do you set the content exactly to the `UIWebView?

Comment: I had fix this issue for now by passing content from my css file into <style> tag by converting whole content into string

Comment: `dict[@"template"]` should give right string. Could you print data converted into string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will convert HTML to `NSString`.

```
NSString *responseInHTML = @"<html><body> Some html string </body></html>";
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[responseInHTML dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

DLOG(@"String = %@",attrStr.string);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve your html by removing \ from string.

Example:

```
NSString *myHTML = [oldHTML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\" withString:@""];
```

Comment: removing \ in the whole html will be of bad consequences... as \ will be removed also in the places where it is needed

Comment: Nice try bro but Sorry this will not going to work because we can't give \ or " as a string individually it will always through an error missing terminate .

Comment: NSString *myHTML = [oldHTML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];

Comment: @Govind. No thanks to you for your contribution. You have fetched some spare time for reading my problem from your busy schedule :)